# jquery not setting the value of checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox

whether or not my variable "showforfamilymember" has a value of true or false it always the show checkbox as checked

```
        <label for="showforfamilymemberchk">Show This Group While Adding Family Member</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="showforfamilymemberchk" id="showforfamilymemberchk" />
```

jQuery

```
var txtshowforfamilymember = $("#showforfamilymemberchk");
txtshowforfamilymember.attr("checked", showforfamilymember);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you setting showforfamilymember ?

If you do it like this it should work

```
var showforfamilymember = false;
```

if you have the value stored let's say in some string "myValue"

```
var showforfamilymember = (myValue.toLowerCase() === 'true');
```

Hope it works

Answer (score 1):

Try using .prop() instead of .attr()

```
txtshowforfamilymember.prop("checked", showforfamilymember);
```